# Output Contents of an Element?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

I am currently creating a tool. That will login into my Krispy Kreme account and then output my saved address. I am currently at the stage where I have managed to use the tool and : log into the account , navigate to the page where my address is saved.

When inspecting the Krispy Kreme page (where my address is) this is the relevant information :

```
address class="block-item_addresses"
div data-id="name">John Smith<
div data-id="lineOne">Flat 7 Big house<
```

I'd ideally like to have all that data saved into one variable : "myaddress" and then output it with `Console.writeline(myaddress);`

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save "John Smith \n Flat 7 Big House", you could use this:

```
string addrss = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("block-item_addresses")).Text;
```

from there, you could create a new `Address` object that contains `string name` and `string address` properties, then save the element string into that object:

```
public class Address
{
    public Address(string name, string address)
    {
         this.name = name;
         this.address = address;
    }

    public string name { get; set; }

    public string address { get; set; }

}
```

To create a new Address object and output its contents:

```
//get element text
string addrss = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("block-item_addresses")).Text;

//separate the element text by new line
var split = addrss.Split(new string[] {"\\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);

//create new Address object
Address address = new Address(split[0], split[1]);

//print Address props
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + address.name);
Console.WriteLine("Address: " + address.address);
```

Comment: @FreddieMoore. So you are saving the page source into a string? If you are navigating to the page using a WebDriver, I would not recommend using the pagesource because you'll have to use string manipulation to get the info you need.

Comment: @FreddieMoore, if you can, please edit your post to include some example code

Answer (score 0):

C# has a [Object.ToString](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) method that can serve to this purpose.

So, you can just create an object that represent this info, with attribute such as name and address and override Object.ToString, returning a String with the content you are interested.